# OpenCV Contrib Modules

Tags: python, opencv, cmake, cmake-gui

I have seen this question pop up several places, but the only time I have seen it answered is through Visual Studio using cpp or on a Linux OS.

I am trying to add contribution modules to OpenCV and for use with Python-Anaconda in Spyder. Specifically, I am looking to add the bgsegm module. I have tried several different ways but with no success.

I have downloaded the current master branches of OpenCV and Opencv_contrib. I put them in a new folder I named opencv-3.0. In opencv I create a new folder named build. I ran command prompt in that folder and used the command:

```
cmake -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH= ..\..\opencv_contrib\modules
```

which returns

```
the source directory "C:/opencv-3.0/opencv_contrib/modules" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt
```

What am I missing on the command line? make -j5? I dont even get the option to run it because of the error.

Alternatively when running from the cmake GUI, I'm not sure what to use as my generator. I do not have Visual Studio and that is what everyone seems to use. Even if I had VS I want to be able to use this in python and Sypder. Suggestions?

Comment: Space between `OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH` and `..\..\opencv_contrib\modules` means that you assign empty value for variable and attempt to use given path as source. Correct call: `cmake -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=..\..\opencv_contrib\modules ..`

Comment: Thank you for responding. I added the space because I was receiving other errors when I did not have it. I see now the error in having it there. When I run the corrected code with .. at the end it returns "--building for: NMake MAkefiles" and then I get the error  "cmake must be run from a shell that can use the compiler cl from the command line." and that my compiler identification is unknown. the full output is multiple lines but this is the jist. I get the feeling I am missing a major part of what is necessary for cmake...like a compiler.

Comment: The error message `cmake must be run ...` looks selfexplanatory. You may also google it. If you will failed to resolve your problem, formulate it **in the question post itself**, not in the comments: On Stack Overflow comments are used only for clarifiing posts(questions, answers) or for request for clarification.

Comment: My apologies, will fix that. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you want to use Python, you will have to compile the OpenCV Contrib Modules yourself before you will be able to use it with Python.

`CMake` generates Makefiles for your compiler (so get one if you don't have one), after that you can compile the Makefile/Visual Studio solution.

The error you're receiving from `CMake` is because you did not specify the OpenCV source directory as the last argument. Follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib#how-to-build-opencv-with-extra-modules) precisely.

So something like:

```
cd "C:/opencv-3.0/build"
cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH="C:/opencv-3.0/opencv_contrib/modules" "C:/opencv-3.0"
```

Comment: I see, so it should go something like cmake makes the file for the compiler, then the compiler build the cv2.py then I can copy that into my anaconda site-packages and actually use the module. Does that sound about right? I was under the impression that cmake did the compiling but I guess not. Do you have a suggestion for a compiler that would be useful in this situation? I would like to avoid Visual Studio if possible. Also when I do specify the source directory, i receive the error that my compiler identification is unkown (makes sense if I don't have one).

Comment: You must do your own research what compiler is best for you. But if you're fresh and just want to get started with something new; I'd suggest to start with a popular Linux distribution, whether or not from a virtual machine.